# Automatically Export a Group | Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

I am wondering if there is a way to automatically export a Group to FTP in Marketing Cloud using an automation.

I've created a Group, using Measures leveraged against our All Subscribers List, and need to export its contents to our FTP on a regular basis. I know that you can export Data Extensions using a Data Extract, but I can't find documentation regarding Lists or Groups.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly you cannot export groups in any standardised way. You can read the tracking types available here, if you need to https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/data_extract_activity/extract_types/

the way to go about it would be to create a query with the same criteria, and then export the results from the targeted data extension.

If you want a list of just bounced or unsubscribed, you can use the following query:

```
select SubscriberKey, EmailAddress
from _Subscribers
where
Status = 'Unsubscribed' OR 
Status = 'Bounced'
```

But note this is a status - not an event within a timeframe

Comment: Do you know how I could query All Subscribers for only the Subscribers with a hard bounce, block bounce or unsubscribe? I'm not super familiar with SQL statements, though that might exceed the scope of this question.

Comment: sure - i'll update my answer

Comment: hope this helps